# How to ask Spring Cloud Config server to checkout configuration from specific branch?

Tags: spring, git, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have following Spring cloud config application.yml:

```
spring: 
  application: 
    name: configserver
  cloud: 
    config: 
      server: 
        git: 
          uri: https://xyz@bitbucket.org/xyz/microservices-configs.git
          username: xyz
          password: xyz
          basedir: target/configs
server:
  port: 8881
```

Following is my `bootstrap.yml` of user microservice:

```
spring: 
  application: 
    name: userservice
  cloud: 
    config: 
      uri: http://localhost:8881/
```

**Scenario - 1**
When I hit config server in browser like this:
`http://localhost:8881/development/userservice-development.yml`
It serves file properly. and when I look at `basedir` i.e. target/config, I see:

```
- userservice.yml  
- gateway.yml
```

Exactly what I wanted, **Since I added this two files only in development branch**.

**Scenario - 2**
When I run my userservice microservice project using following command:
`mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=development`

It fetches the right file from git, but **it checkout from master branch !** but **not from the development branch** as I am expecting. am I expecting right ?  (FYI I have both development and production yml in master branch)

So the question is, how do we go for using config server ? Is there any configuration which we can set to fetch yml from that particular branch only ? I believe we need to set some label, because as per documentation, default label is master. Can anyone let me know how do we go for setting label in above scenario ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_locating_remote_configuration_resources), the configuration you want to set in your config client is:

```
spring.cloud.config.label=mybranch
```

Where `mybranch` is an existing branch in your git repo.

Comment: Thanks. I was setting label all into config server. so is it all about the binding in config client application ? it was little confusing to decide between server's or client's `spring.cloud.config` property.

Comment: My branch has a slash (/), so how do I configure that? I tried `spring.cloud.config.label=release/1.0.0,release_1.0.0,release(_)1.0.0` but does not work

Comment: I figured out. It should be `release(_)1.0.0`

Comment: @spencergibb - Any idea about having native profile, how to handle label in that case? Any pointers?

Comment: For me above mentioned property didn't work and when I changed to following it worked fine
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label = BranchName
. I am using Spring Boot version 2.1.3.RELEASE and spring-cloud-config-server version 2.1.1.RELEASE.

Comment: it should be spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=branchname and also, the branchname should not contain '/' - s

Comment: Who calls a branch a "label"? Just call it a branch should be `spring.cloud.config.branch`

Comment: because other repositories, such as jdbc or vault have no concept of branch

Comment: It can also be used for a tag or a commit id, so not limited to just a branch. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#_locating_remote_configuration_resources

Answer (score 23):

You can specify the default branch (more generally, Git label) that a config server uses if a client does not specify the label, via property `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label`, perhaps this is what you are after? Certainly solves the issue for me!

Answer (score 17):

If only use the branch in a yml file just configure:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git: 
          uri: https://gitlab.com/somerepo.git
          username: someuser
          password: somepass
          default-label: branchname
```

Comment: Branchname also should not contain slashes /, otherwise it will not work

Comment: Then what should we replace the slashes with, in the branchname?

Comment: @user5163359 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435897/how-to-escape-a-slash-character-within-a-branch-name-label-in-spring-cloud-con

Answer (score 15):

Config server designed to use profile to separate environment.
Example:

```
/{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{application}-{profile}.properties
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
```

The branching make configuration inconsistency.

Concept of config server is based on 12-factor config  (http://12factor.net/config ) .

Check it out for detail reason.