# How to escape a slash character within a branch name (label) in Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

In Spring Cloud Config, if you have a branch (label) that contains a `/`, it wouldn't fetch the correct branch from cloud config server.

Consider the following properties in `bootstrap.yml` of our product `TheApp`;

```
spring:
  application:
    name: TheApp
  profiles:
    active: test
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://myconfigserver.com
```

And we include the branch `feature/new` for my cloud config label, using it directly as below;

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      label: feature/new
```

Since this will translate to the following RESTful call to config server from our `TheApp` application;

```
http://myconfigserver.com/{name}/{profile}/{label}
```

which will be;

```
http://myconfigserver.com/TheApp/test/feature/new
```

Though it is obvious this call will not work due to the extra `/` from our label name. How to use a label containing `/` within this configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is very simple, just replace `/` that is breaking the call to the config server with `(_)`, so for example `feature/new` will be `feature(_)new` within our bootstrap.yml;

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      label: feature(_)new
```

And the RESTful call to config server will be;

```
http://myconfigserver.com/TheApp/test/feature(_)new
```

Which will result a successful fetch of the correct branch, namely `feature/new`

For more details; check [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/652), and [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/21e46b0192682ab3a3cb6bb70d7c2a2a40add9ab).