# Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm working on ***Spring Boot 2.4.2.RELEASE*** and developing `config-server` for my microservices project. Below is the my code which I develop so far.

ConfigServerApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=config-server

server.port=9296

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/shabbirdwd53/config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.example.demo.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1305) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthContributorRegistry(HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:722) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1598) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1451) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:714) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref master cannot be resolved
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:254) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.checkout(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:422) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.initClonedRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:351) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:255) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Your branch name is main instead of master, so change this following [How to ask Spring Cloud Config server to checkout configuration from specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195002/how-to-ask-spring-cloud-config-server-to-checkout-configuration-from-specific-br)

Comment: @samabcde - Hey I already tried that, but it still gives the same error. Any other help ?

`spring.cloud.config.label=main`

Comment: I simply renamed it from `main` to `master` and its working fine now

Comment: My bad, I should test it, the correct configuration should be `default-label` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991650/resolved-org-springframework-cloud-config-server-environment-nosuchlabelexcepti)

Comment: @samabcde - hey, its ok, let me quickly see if that works on not .. Thanks!

Comment: @samabcde - Thanks `spring.cloud.config.label=main` code is working!

Comment: I use default-label set to main. It fails to startup. I set it to master, it can start up. I have created a git repository online, but it does not have any code inside yet, let alone be any branch.  So why then set to master work, but not main?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Modify application.yml files

```
spring:
  application:
    name: CONFIG-SERVER
  
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git: 
          uri: https://github.com/kishanc16/config-server
          default-label: main
          clone-on-start: true
```

Comment: I was getting a similar issue and after making the changes. The error is gone. Thank you, Kishan a lot.

Answer (score 12):

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have a `main` branch in your git repo else you can use `master` instead:

- `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main`

OR

- `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master`

Answer (score 1):

create a xyz.txt file in local git repo then copy configurations of services into that file and the add and commit that. after that go into eclipse config-server service and **right click on project and buildpath-> configure build path ->java build path ->link resources -> add path of local .git**

now in application.properties add these :

```
spring.application.name=spring-config-server,spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file://G:/microservices/git-config-dir,spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master,server.port=8888
```

now you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

in my case branch is master so added below changes to resolve the issue
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master